# Is 'bool' 1 or 2 bytes in C++Builder? I'm getting conflicting results

Tags: c++, c++builder

The following code returns a `bool` in the `AL` CPU register:

```
bool Exiting;
bool WINAPI IsExiting()
{
   return Exiting;
}
```

which compiles to:

```
00488BA4 55               push ebp
00488BA5 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
00488BA7 6843475300       push $00534743
00488BAC 83C4F4           add esp,-$0c
00488BAF C745F8CC8B4800   mov [ebp-$08],$00488bcc
00488BB6 C745F001000000   mov [ebp-$10],$00000001
00488BBD A0B0C0A900       mov al,[$00a9c0b0] <------------------ AL has the result
00488BC2 896DFC           mov [ebp-$04],ebp
00488BC5 896DFC           mov [ebp-$04],ebp
00488BC8 8BE5             mov esp,ebp
00488BCA 5D               pop ebp
00488BCB C3               ret
```

But I've found when calling it:

```
if (!IsExiting()) {
  task1
}
if (!IsExiting()) {
  task2
}
```

task1 works, task2 doesn't always. The reason is:

```
if (!IsExiting())
```

compiles down to:

```
0040419E E8014A0800       call IsExiting()
004041A3 6685C0           test ax,ax     <------ bool is stored in AL, but test is on AX
004041A6 755C             jnz $00404204
```

Am I missing something? `AX` is 16 bits, `AL` is 8 bits.

Is this a compiler error, or am I being stupid somehow?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. I guess `bool WINAPI IsExiting()` is defined in several compilation units with different `WINAPI` macros.

Comment: `mov al` is for `pascal` calling convention, thus I guess the asm you shown is wrong for `WINAPI` call that must use `stdcall` calling convention and `mov eax`.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I had a difference in the function declaration. For reasons I was not able to include the header file of the IsExiting, which correctly declared it as

```
bool WINAPI IsExiting();
```

But the function was declared (incorrectly) locally in the calling file as

```
short WINAPI IsExiting();
```

I was being stupid somehow. (funny how by asking the question on StackOverflow, you are then able to find the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. Stop using `WINAPI` in your functions.

Long answer. You should avoid using `WINAPI` in your functions. You may use a similar macro only for functions of a public API and should use another than `WINAPI` name. The calling convention for private functions should be set up in the project/compiler settings.

Comment: I disagree with this answer, as WINAPI is a common standard of declaration, and works well with windows. (On Linux it's redefined as nothing)  The error had nothing to do with WINAPI, but your answer did get me thinking in the right direction (see my answer).

Comment: @iplayfast `WINAPI` maps to `__stdcall` on Windows. There is no good reason to use `__stdcall` on internal functions that are not exported in public APIs. Most C/C++ compilers (including C++Builder) default to `__cdecl` when no calling convention is specified in code. The default can usually be changed in compiler settings. So, unless there is a specific reason to specify a particular convention (interop, etc), you should just omit the convention entirely from your own declarations and let the compiler use its default convention. IOW `bool WINAPI IsExiting()` should be `bool IsExiting()`.